# Having issue in Installing label-studio via python 3.7

Tags: python, pip, localhost, rpa

I am installing label-studio via python 3.7.
I have used this command for installing label-studio.

```
py -m pip install label-studio
```

I am following the instructions from official site.

```
# Requires >=Python3.6, <3.9
pip install label-studio

# Start the server at http://localhost:8080
label-studio
```

but when I used to launch this program it gives the following error in cmd.

```
'label-studio' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I am using windows 10.

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
py -m label-studio
```

Your `<path/to/python/exe>\Scripts` is not in `PATH`. 
Have you checked the `Add Python 3.7 to PATH` option when installing python?

Comment: I have added path of the python as cmd is showing the version of python and pip.

Comment: Python 3.7.8  , Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\python.exe: No module named label-studio. Now showing this error

Comment: Try adding `%APPDATA%\Python\Python37\Scripts` to PATH as an temporary solution ( i.e. `set PATH=%PATH%%APPDATA%\Python\Python37\Scripts;`)
You probably installed the package in the user directory.

Comment: I have set the path where package is installed. and try to run the label-studio but same error persists.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way is to use venv:

```
python3 -m venv c:\path\to\myenv
c:\path\to\myenv\Scripts\activate.bat
pip install -U label-studio
label-studio
```